# CefSharp Chromium page loading never completes

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, cefsharp

I need my ChromiumWebBrowser to load all of the pages in array of urls, execute javascript on every one of them and then download their sources. I wrote a following piece of code:

```
            ChromiumWebBrowser[] chromium = new ChromiumWebBrowser[offersLinks.Count()];                     
            for(int i = 0; i < offersLinks.Count(); ++i)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Page " + (i + 1) + "/" + offersLinks.Count());
                chromium[i] = new ChromiumWebBrowser(offersLinks[i]);
                chromium[i].FrameLoadEnd += async (sender, args) =>
                {
                    //Wait for the MainFrame to finish loading
                    if (args.Frame.IsMain)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Loaded.");
                        if (chromium[i].CanExecuteJavascriptInMainFrame)
                        {
                            JavascriptResponse response = await chromium[i].EvaluateScriptAsync(javascript);

                            if (response.Result != null)
                            {
                                Debug.WriteLine(response.Message);
                            }
                        }

                        chromium[i].ViewSource();
                        string html = await chromium[i].GetSourceAsync();
                    }
                };
            }
```

However, for some reason, the code inside FrameLoadEnd callback never executes. Could you explain it to me?

Comment: Is there a method you need to call on the ChromiumWebBrowser objects to actually load the offerLinks[i] URL?  I don't see any reason why the event handler is not being called unless the page is never loaded.

Comment: @alec The page should be loaded in costructor, after setting the URL.

Comment: you are correct but it looks like there are issues where it doesn't load the URL passed into the constructor 100% of the time.

"WinForms workaround for certain scenarios fails to load the Url passed into the ChromiumWebBrowser constructor (initial details in #2234 (comment) has been reverted in 821a44f as the issue appears to be resolved."

Could you try explicitly calling the Load method with the URL after constructing the ChromiumWebBrowser objects to see if the behavior is any different?

Comment: @alec, I've already tried it, but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: Are you using CefSharp.OffScreen? You cannot use the WPF or WinForms versions like your example code above

Comment: @amaitland you're right, thanks! Could you post that as an answer so I could accept it?

Comment: Answer posted, feel free to propose some edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cases when you don't require a `UI` it's best to use [CefSharp.OffScreen](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CefSharp.OffScreen)

The `WPF` and `WinForms` versions of `CefSharp` won't start loading until they are attached to the `UI`.